# What is the difference between a query and transaction in SQL?

Tags: sql

Studying SQL for first time and my teacher says that a query will always return some sort of information while a transaction will make data to be read or put into the database. I am confused because why do people then say INSERT is a query in SQL? Could someone please kindly explain to a beginner?

Comment: The "Q" in SQL stands for "Query": All SQL is a "query" even if it doesn't return anything (eg a `create table` query) - search for DDL, DML and DCL). All queries are run within a transaction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A query usually refers to a `SELECT` statement, but may also refer to data modifications as well -- `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `MERGE` are common DML ("data modification language") statements.  Personally, I would call these four operations *DML statements* and reserve *query* for `SELECT` statements; I find this a useful distinction.

Databases implement a set of properties called ACID properties.  These basically say that any SQL statement sees consistent data, regardless of what else is going on in the database.  A simple way to think of about these is that all operations are serialized -- one statement completes before another begins, even in a multi-user environment.  Serialization guarantees that operations are isolated from each other.  In practice, serialization is very expensive and databases have other mechanisms to ensure integrity, but it is a useful abstraction when learning about the concepts.

What are transactions?  Transactions are the mechanism that databases use to ensure the integrity of the data when data is being modified.  Transactions often consist of one statement that modifies the data.  But that is not necessary.  In fact, you can have a complex set of data transformations within a single transaction.

The three key operations on a transactions are:

- BEGIN TRANSACTION:  Tell the database that a transaction is beginning.  All changes within the transaction are invisible to other users while the transaction is "active".
- COMMIT TRANSACTION:  Make all the changes visible in the database.  Conceptually, this happens instantaneously.  The database guarantees that other users will not see partial changes to the data (i.e. enforces data integrity).
- ROLLBACK TRANSACTION:  Undo all the work.  No other users ever see the changes.

Note:  Many databases have options to weaken the data integrity.  These can be useful for performance reasons *for users who know what they are doing*.

I should note that if all operations on a database are `SELECT` statements, then transactions are not necessary.  The data is not changing, so the view of the data is consistent.  So transactions are generally associated with DML statements.

Answer (score 3):

A simple explanation would be like this `Query is a single instruction like SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE etc` and `transaction is group of query to perform particular task`

- in case of money transaction operation, there are multiple tasks we need to perform like `select account`, `verify balance`, `debit balance` and `credit balance` so this 4 queries can be together an form a txn.

Comment: i guess you're trying to say when we're updating multiple tables at the same time, we should use transactions to guarantee data consistency, whereas UPDATE, DELETE are updating a single table so they're not a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Working with SQL DBs you got both - transactions and queries. Here a simple explanation:

- Queries are operations to CRUD (create (*insert*), update (*set*), read (*select*), delete (*delete*)) data inside a table.
- The transaction is more or less the process of a single or multiple statements/queries/operations getting executed.

So this means a transaction contains some interactions and a query is an example of 1 kind of interaction. Important to know is that transactions are like buying stuff online. You operate and mark things you want to buy but only if you click "buy" you will finally get and pay for the stuff. For transactions, that means they need to be committed afterwards otherwise it will be undone again (rollback). Mostly your frameworks will commit changes automatically after each interaction and end the transaction with it.

Comment in case you got more questions.

Comment: So does a transaction just make sure that the query will work as intended and not do something wrong to the database? Would a transaction count as a query itself? @LemglBoy